# Converting Synchronous code to Asynchronous code in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am trying to make a method of mine into something that can be called asynchronously.

Normally from the AddQueue Method, I would just call the ListOfJobsInQueue methods in the WorkingSession class, get its result and be done with it.

Using what info I could find regarding Async programming on here, I have done up the below code, but it seems to be getting stuck on the **CurrentPageCode** property call.

It does not even get to the **MessageBox.Show("Processing complete with " + queueResult.Count + " rows");** line.

Could someone please assist and show me where I'm going wrong?

```
    //Primary Class

    public void AddQueue()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(GetJobsFromQueueAsync().Result.Count().ToString());
    }

    async Task<List<string>> GetJobsFromQueueAsync()
    {
        Task<List<string>> getJobsTask = WorkingSession.GetlistOfJobsAsync();
        List<string> queueResult = await getJobsTask;
        MessageBox.Show("Processing complete with " + queueResult.Count + " rows");
        return queueResult;
    }

    //***

    //WorkingSession Class

    public Task<List<string>> GetlistOfJobsAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run<List<string>>(() =>
        {
            return ListOfJobsInQueue();
        });
    }

    public List<string> ListOfJobsInQueue()
    {
        if (CurrentPageCode == "CS1")
        {
            List<string> actionList = new List<string>();
            short pageNum = PageCurrent;
            short pageMax = PageMax;

            for (short atPage = pageNum; atPage <= pageMax; atPage++)
            {
                //Scan each job on the current queue page
                for (int lineNum = 5; lineNum < 18; lineNum++)
                {
                    string reference = GetJobText(new Coordinate { row = lineNum });
                    actionList.Add(reference);
                }
                //Once finished with this job page, goto the next
                SendCMDKey(Mnemonic.F8);
            }
            return actionList;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    //Other method / property signatures (for reference)

    public string CurrentPageCode;
    public bool SendCMDKey(Mnemonic command)
    public string GetJobText(Coordinate coordinate)

    //***
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can use the `async/await` approach with your own "async" call can you? (Unless you implement it as a proper/traditional re-entrant function). The examples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx suggests that the approach you have taken will only work with framework API methods that are designed for `async` use?

Comment: Thats not the impression I got, besides I did another test sample before this project and it worked fine, it was a less complicated scenario though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deadlock problem is actually this method:

```
public void AddQueue()
{
    MessageBox.Show(GetJobsFromQueueAsync().Result.Count().ToString());
}
```

Calling `Task.Wait` or `Task<T>.Result` should be avoided in `async` code. [I explain the deadlock in full on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), but the summary version is that `await` will capture a context (in this case, the UI context) and attempt to resume its `async` method on that context (in this case, on the UI thread). With some contexts (e.g., the UI context), if you block a thread in that context (e.g., calling `Task<T>.Result` on the UI thread), then the `async` method cannot resume on that context, causing a deadlock.

To fix it, use `async` all the way:

```
public async Task AddQueueAsync()
{
    var jobs = await GetJobsFromQueueAsync();
    MessageBox.Show(jobs.Count().ToString());
}
```

This code is also not ideal, though in a much more subtle way:

```
public Task<List<string>> GetlistOfJobsAsync()
{
    return Task.Run<List<string>>(() =>
    {
        return ListOfJobsInQueue();
    });
}
```

By wrapping an entire method's logic in `Task.Run`, what you're really doing is writing a "fake asynchronous" method. It's got an asynchronous signature but the logic is just synchronous work on a background thread.

It's best to push any `Task.Run` use as far towards the UI layer as possible; keep it out of any reusable library methods. Make your APIs tell the truth: have synchronous signatures for synchronous work. [I have a blog series that goes into detail](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html).

Comment: Given that `AddQueue` has return type `void`, and contains UI work (`MessageBox.Show`) what is the advantage of converting that into `async Task AddQueueAsync`? I thought such a method was a logical place to use `Task.Run` to shift into async programming. How about this: `public void AddQueue() { Task.Run(() => ListOfJobsInQueue()).ContinueWith((t1) => MessageBox.Show(t1.Result.Count.ToString())); }`?  Hmm, maybe that doesn't continue on UI thread.

Comment: ... to explain *why* I'm interested in not changing the signature of `AddQueue`: legacy code with thousands of methods over dozens of projects - determining how to add `async` where its really needed, without having to touch so many methods.  There are a lot of `void` methods; I think a fair number of those can be "fire-and-forget" to avoid "spreading" `async` through the whole code. Though now I'm seeing this is easy to screw up: its not obvious which methods have side-effects that their callers assume happen before return. I think I've answered my own question. It is safer to let it spread.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: Yes, it is (usually) safer to let it spread. If you want to do a partial refactoring, check out my [sync over async article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development). "Fire and forget" is dangerous because it can swallow exceptions, in addition to the side effect issues.

Comment: If you have a large refactoring, you can draw a line at one point and block like `Task.Run(() => ...).GetAwaiter().GetResult()` which is safe if `...` can run on a background thread. You lose the benefits of asynchrony (since all the "asynchronous" code is called in a blocking fashion), but you get to take a breath in the middle of a large refactor and maybe work on something else for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest that I can

```
   public async Task<int> GetWorkFlowStageAsync(string tracker,CancellationToken? token = null)
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(0);
        }
```

Comment: When adding a new answer to an old question, please explain what is the benefit of your answer, versus the already existing answer. Also, just posting a piece of code, with no explanation, is rarely useful. What are you demonstrating? What code in the question, or in the existing answer, are you replacing with this snippet of code? When might someone want to use your approach? I don't know if my questions apply to your answer; the important point is to please write down more about your code.